# Can Bob, as the client, share any information about his project in any way he wants?

Tags: business, liability, corporate-law, data-protection, data-ownership

Bob hires vendor A and vendor B independently to work on a project for Bob. The two vendors are not partners, they work independently and do not communicate with each other although they are aware of each other existence.

Bob likes to forward emails from one to another without redacting PII or sensitive information. Bob likes to copy and paste excerpt of emails from one to another without seeking consent either. The emails might have sensitive information that could impact how vendor A and B perform on the project if the other were to see it. The emails could have information that will affect the relationship between vendor A and B and their professional image in the industry.

Can Bob, as the client, share any information about his project in any way he wants?

Comment: What kind of NDA is there? Typically, if you don’t want someone sharing your proprietary information, you give them an NDA.

Comment: @Jen Suppose Bob forwards A's emails to B and B's to A without CCing or asking permission from either.

Comment: @cpast Do you mean if the vendors request Client to sign NDA?

Comment: Yes. When vendors are sharing their proprietary info with a client, it’s common to give the client an NDA to protect that info.